# Raw type 'Error' is not expressible by any literal

Tags: swift, swift3

This piece of code is not longer running in Swift 3. Any idea?

CODE:

```
public enum ErrorResponse : Error {
    case Error(Int, Data?, Error)
}
```

ERROR:

```
/Swaggers/Models.swift:13:29: Raw type 'Error' is not expressible by any literal
```

Answer (score 6):

You haven't provided enough code to reproduce the issue (this compiles fine as written). However, the `ErrorType` protocol was renamed to `Error` in Swift 3. You likely have some type called `Error` elsewhere in your system, and that's causing confusion. The solution is to be explicit about which `Error` type you mean:

```
public enum ErrorResponse : Swift.Error {
```